# Indeterminate forms in numerical analysis

Tags: numerical-methods, regression, linear-regression

I want to fit data to an exponential model, but the table given to me in the exercise contains a $0$ as a value for the independent variable, which is making the argument of the exponential indeterminate. My model is $y=ae^{b/x}$. The goal is to linearize this and apply linear regression.

Since the value of $y(0)$ in the data table is finite, I deduced that $b$ should be negative (the values of $x$ in the table are increasing, so I'm taking the limit from the right), and that $a=y(0)$.

My problem is with the linearization step.

- **Option 1**: Should I just disregard $(0,\,y(0))$ as a data point and proceed to use $\ln y=\ln a+b(1/x)$,
- **Option 2:** or should I use it as mentioned above to deduce $a$, and fit the data to $\underbrace{(1/b)}_{\text{slope}}x+\underbrace{0}_{\text{intercept}}=\frac1{\ln(y/a)}$?

My issue with the first option is obviously letting go of data. As for the second option, the indeterminacy is still present for $y=a$, and, should I again disregard the first data point, I doubt that the formula for the intercept will give me $0$, so that I will have to decide on which value to use.

As a third option, I thought of using a value like $10^{-6}$ instead of $0$, since we're doing approximations anyhow.

Any tips? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=a\:e^{b/x}$$
$$\ln(y)=\ln(a)+\frac{b}{x}$$
$$x\ln(y)=\ln(a)\:x+b$$
Let :
$$Y=x\ln(y)\quad\text{and}\quad c=\ln(a)$$
Compute the data $Y(x)=x\ln\left(y(x)\right)$.

Try the linear regression for $b$ and $c$ :
$$Y=b+c\:x$$

Comment: right, there's nothing that prevents me from "combining" the variables. thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Jean ! Long time no see. Are you OK ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi Claude ! Happy to meet you again ! Hold on and all the best.